# Pdf document wont attach to iOS email

Tags: swift, email, pdf, attachment

I'm having problems getting this PDF document I created to attach to an email. So basically in my app I get the user to type in some text via a `UITextfied` and then take that text and put in into a PDF document. I then want the user to be able to send this PDF as an email attachment when clicking a button. Any thoughts on where I went wrong attaching this pdf as a attachment?

I got this code from [Attach a PDF file to email - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423583/attach-a-file-to-email-swift) and I just modified it but still no attachment. Also its coming up with the error

> stringByAppendingPathComponent is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathCompenent on NSURL instead.

Had a look at this [stringByAppendingPathComponent is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501627/stringbyappendingpathcomponent-is-unavailable) and it doesnt make sense to me sorry.

```
//find the file and the path
let fileName: String = self.tfEssayTopicTitle.text!
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String

let pdfFileName = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName + ".pdf")
let fileData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pdfFileName)
mailVC.addAttachmentData(fileData!, mimeType: "application/pdf", fileName: pdfFileName)
```

Comment: Hi rmaddy, I thought I did append the pdfFileName to documentsPath by creating using the documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName + ".pdf"). Then I passed it to fileData. Is that not the way? If not, is it meant to look something like this?... let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true).stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName + ".pdf")

Comment: My mistake. I looked at your code incorrectly.

Comment: no worries.. will just keep waiting to see if anyone else has any ideas.. thanks you for your help though... =)